# Remote desktop conection from Ubuntu 18.04 to Windows 8

Tags: remote-desktop, ip-address

I am trying to establish a connection from my Ubuntu 18 to a client's machine via Internet (for support purposes). My problem is how to specify the remote machine using IP address since they share one public IP to their LAN. So the client uses private IP. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

1) Get the clients IT team to port forward the RDP ports to the clients PC. I'm sure they will love that suggestion.

2) Allow the client an ssh connection to your machine and have him/her establish the connection. Something like:

`ssh -R 3389:localhost:3389 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes <client>@<your IP>`

Then you would just connect to localhost:3389

This would probably violate the clients IT policy as well.

Comment: They really don't have any technical person. I'm supposed to guide them on how to go about it. I last used Windows over 10yrs ago. I'll see how this goes on phone. Thanks